# Append de uma lista em um dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando fazer um append de uma lista em um dataframe no Python
Quero colocar os 6 primeiros números na mesma linha e depois ir adicionando linha por linha, até completar as colunas
*Eu tentei gerar os dados para facilitar, abaixo:*

```
import pandas as pd
import random

randomlist = []
for i in range(0,30):
    n = random.randint(1,30)
    randomlist.append(n)

randomlist = [30, 11, 18, 11, 28, 18, 22, 18, 20, 10, 11, 6, 29, 1, 11, 15, 3, 4, 17, 11, 17, 18, 27, 25, 11, 10, 7, 4, 18, 27]

lista_colunas = ['Carro', 'Moto', 'Barco', 'Patinete', 'Mobilete', 'Skate']
lista_index = ['Entre 1 a 5', 'Entre 6 a 10', 'Entre 11 a 15', 'Entre 16 a 20', 'Entre 21 a 25']
```

**Abaixo o resultado desejado:**

[image: Tabela_resultado]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando ao *DataFrames* definido abaixo como base para o exercício mental:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lista_colunas = ['Carro', 'Moto', 'Barco', 'Patinete', 'Mobilete', 'Skate']
lista_index = ['Entre 1 a 5', 'Entre 6 a 10', 'Entre 11 a 15', 'Entre 16 a 20', 'Entre 21 a 25']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=lista_index, columns=lista_colunas)
print(df)
```

```
              Carro Moto Barco Patinete Mobilete Skate
Entre 1 a 5     NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN
Entre 6 a 10    NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN
Entre 11 a 15   NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN
Entre 16 a 20   NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN
Entre 21 a 25   NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN   NaN
```

Ao trabalhar com [*DataFrames*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) acesse um grupo de colunas ou linhas pelo índice com [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).
Também considere o uso do [*Numpy*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/index.html). A função [`numpy.random.randint()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) retorna uma [ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html?highlight=ndarray#numpy.ndarray) de inteiros aleatórios, no exemplo abaixo é retornada uma matriz de cinco linhas por seis colunas onde cada linha substituirá a linha correspondente do *DataFrame*:

```python
randomlist = np.random.randint(30, size=(5,6))   #Cria um a matriz de 5 linhas por 6 colunas de inteiros com aleatórios no intervalo [0,30[.
df.iloc[:] = randomlist                          #Substitui linha a linha no df pelas linhas de randomlist
print(df)
```

```
              Carro Moto Barco Patinete Mobilete Skate
Entre 1 a 5      12    2     5       16        3     6
Entre 6 a 10     21   24    10        1       13     2
Entre 11 a 15    29   15     8        3        1    10
Entre 16 a 20    17   16     4       21       20    12
Entre 21 a 25    18   10    27       26       26     4
```

Caso a entrada venha obrigatoriamente de [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), use a função [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html?highlight=array#numpy.array) para obter o *ndarray* de inteiros com a função [`numpy.split()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) para quebrar o array em matriz de cinco linhas e seis colunas:

```python
randomlist = np.array([30, 11, 18, 11, 28, 18, 22, 18, 20, 10, 11, 6, 29, 1, 11, 15, 3, 4, 17, 11, 17, 18, 27, 25, 11, 10, 7, 4, 18, 27])
df.iloc[:] = np.split(randomlist, 5)            #Quebra o array de 30 elementos  numa matriz de 5 linhas por 6 colunas.
print(df)
```

```
              Carro Moto Barco Patinete Mobilete Skate
Entre 1 a 5      30   11    18       11       28    18
Entre 6 a 10     22   18    20       10       11     6
Entre 11 a 15    29    1    11       15        3     4
Entre 16 a 20    17   11    17       18       27    25
Entre 21 a 25    11   10     7        4       18    27
```

Caso não queira usar *Numpy* ou por achar *Numpy* uma solução *overkill* ou por simplesmente não gostar do *Numpy* pode fazer usando [compreensão de lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) para quebrar a lista em questão a cada seis elementos:

```python
randomlist = [30, 11, 18, 11, 28, 18, 22, 18, 20, 10, 11, 6, 29, 1, 11, 15, 3, 4, 17, 11, 17, 18, 27, 25, 11, 10, 7, 4, 18, 27]
df.iloc[:] = [randomlist[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(randomlist), 6)]
df
```

```
              Carro Moto Barco Patinete Mobilete Skate
Entre 1 a 5      30   11    18       11       28    18
Entre 6 a 10     22   18    20       10       11     6
Entre 11 a 15    29    1    11       15        3     4
Entre 16 a 20    17   11    17       18       27    25
Entre 21 a 25    11   10     7        4       18    27
```

<sup>Teste os exemplos acima no [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NACIpkPdHrq0chIaQnOrAOxyXhIF60Zd?usp=sharing)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução é usando [*dict comprehension*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/) (ou "compreensão de dicionário") fracionando `randomlist` em partes iguais de acordo com a quantidade de colunas de `lista_colunas`.

```
>>> qtd_linhas = len(randomlist) / len(lista_colunas)
>>> data = { lista_colunas[n] : randomlist[qtd_linhas * n : qtd_linhas * (n + 1)]
               for n in range(qtd_linhas + 1) }
>>> print(data)
{'Barco': [11, 6, 29, 1, 11], 'Carro': [30, 11, 18, 11, 28], 'Moto': [18, 22, 18, 20, 10], 'Patinete': [15, 3, 4, 17, 11], 'Skate': [10, 7, 4, 18, 27], 'Mobilete': [17, 18, 27, 25, 11]}
```

Para ilustrar melhor a composição desse dicionário, é feito um *slice* em `randomlist` de acordo com o valor de `n` (vai de 0 até 5 neste exemplo) e `qtd_linhas` (neste exemplo, 5):

```
# qtd_linhas = 5
# n = 0
randomlist[0:5] # resultado de randomlist[5 * 0 : 5 * (0 + 1)]
# n = 1
randomlist[5:10] # resultado de randomlist[5 * 1 : 5 * (1 + 1)]
# n = 2
randomlist[10:15] # resultado de randomlist[5 * 2 : 5 * (2 + 1)]
.
.
.
# n = 5
randomlist[25:30] # resultado de randomlist[5 * 5 : 5 * (5 + 1)]
```

Por fim, a criação do dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)
   Barco  Carro  Mobilete  Moto  Patinete  Skate
0     11     30        17    18        15     10
1      6     11        18    22         3      7
2     29     18        27    18         4      4
3      1     11        25    20        17     18
4     11     28        11    10        11     27
```

---

**EDIT:** A variável `lista_index` me passou despercebida quando respondi a pergunta originalmente, portanto em vez da divisão para obter a quantidade de linhas o melhor a fazer seria simplesmente verificar o tamanho dessa lista com:

```
qtd_linhas = len(lista_index)
```

Ainda utilizando a variável `lista_index`, ficou faltando especificar a adição dos índices por linha do dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index = lista_index
```